# How to emit different signals depending on the argument received from another signal

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals, pyside2, qthread

I'm preparing a PySide2 application which receives data from a database. Every time a value is changed in the DB, a signal is emited from a QThread. The Signal would contain a list of  names, corresponding to secondary signals to be triggered.
So far I have the program running for a fixed secondary signal, to say. But I fail to programmatically choose the signal as function of the arguments of another one.

My first attempt is to generate a dictionary with my signals, so I can call them by name. But sorting Signals inside a dictionary or list doesn't work. If I try:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class myapp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    sig0 = QtCore.Signal()
    kmap = {'sig0' : QtCore.Signal() }

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.li = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lo = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        ## Straight signal
        #self.li.returnPressed.connect(self.changel0)

        ## Using own signal
        #self.li.returnPressed.connect(self.sig0)
        #self.sig0.connect(self.changel0)

        ## Using a signal in array or dict, doesnt work
        self.li.returnPressed.connect(self.kmap['sig0'])
        self.kmap['sig0'].connect(self.changel0)

        self.vl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vl.addWidget(self.li)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.lo)
        self.setLayout(self.vl)

    def changel0(self):
        text = self.li.text()
        self.lo.setText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = myapp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

would fail, giving me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtCore.Signal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

How could I choose the signal to send depending on another variable (signal_name) then?

Comment: Just connect to a function that checks the argument (keys and values, if it's a dict) and eventually emit the related signal or directly call the preferred function.

Comment: That approach works. The only problem is I would have more than 100 signals, and creating a switch case for each doesn't sound practical to me. The idea is that the argument passed from the first signal would be directly the name of the second signal to send.

Comment: Why do you have all those different signals? Does each one connect to a different slot? What exactly do the slots do?

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, exactly. Im preparing kind of Model/View in which the data (state of all the devices in my app are hold in a DB). When there is a change in any of the states, the DB sends a log with information, and a series of variables that 'need to be reviewed'. The pyQt app only displays those changes. Because the state can be displayed in several widgets/windows, I send a signal for every one...

Comment: @VictorModamio having 100 signals doesn't seem a good solution either. Instead of using the signal name as argument, just use the *function*. You could add a form of "subscription" for each target function for which a certain string corresponds to that function. Or you could even use function names and then access them using `getattr`. I sincerely doubt that having hundreds of signals is the only possible solution, nor I think it could be the best one. And even assuming it would, you cannot simply use a `dict` for it, not like you're trying: signals must be created as unbound class attributes.

Comment: It's still not clear why you need to use multiple signals. Is there a one-to-one mapping between the signals and slots? Why can't you just call the slots with `getattr`?

Comment: @VictorModamio only use `gettattr(self, 'sig0').connect(self.changel0)`

Comment: perfect! thanks all. If I were using a signal for each variable, the getattr() method does the job. I can connect signals to slots and emit an specific signal by its name. @ekhumoro yes, I could also just call the slots with getattr(), but that would imply that I know in advance the slots to call. The app can have several windows showing few common variables, and might be created in runtime. I like the signals and slots to be completely unaware of each other.

Comment: @VictorModamio Unfortunately, without a proper example that would show and clarify what you're trying to do it's difficult to give you valid suggestions, but from what you're describing it's possible that you're probably thinking it in the wrong way. Assuming that each window should only receive certain signals (or values), maybe the solution would be to just use one signal and then in the receiver's slot of that window decide if the argument should be handled or not: that's similar to the concept I wrote above, which is probably still better, as you'd only have one connected function.